# How to return a specific response from DRF Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If you look at the try/except block under is_valid() method, I'm trying to check if an object exists and if so, return a 202 error.  My question is can I directly return a a response from the serializer or do I need to raise a specific exception and then handle the exception in the views?

```
class CreateJobSerializer(GenericSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('name',)
        validators = []


    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_data'):
            super(CreateJobSerializer, self).clean_ids()
            try:
                Job.objects.get(name=self.initial_data['name'])
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            except:
                return super().is_valid(raise_exception)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all **HTTP_202** is not an error status. The description for 202 is

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.

You can do such type of validations directly from the serializer. For example

```
class CreateJobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('name',)

    def validate_name(self, value):
        if Job.objects.filter(name=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Name already exist")
        return value
```

If you still want to use HTTP_202 then Create new exception by inheriting default `APIException` and override `status_code` to 202. Now raise the new exception.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class APIException202(APIException):
    status_code = 202

class CreateJobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('name',)

    def validate_name(self, value):
        if Job.objects.filter(name=value).exists():
            raise APIException202("Name already exist")
        return value
```

And in view use `is_valid` method for validation

```
serializer = CreateJobSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

`serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` will do the validation and raise errors with proper status code that you have defined

Comment: This is almost working, but I can't figure out why I am getting this error now: Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status' I have imported status but still error

Comment: Sorry my bad. we cant add status_code directly. Have to create new exception from  `APIException` and override status code. I have updated my answer. Please check it. And feel free to ask if any errors happens

Answer (score 2):

we have to validate data in serializers like below code

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class CreateJobSerializer(GenericSerializer):

  def validate_name(self, name):
     if Job.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
        raise APIEXception(
            detail="Job with this name already exists",
            status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED
        )
     return name

  class Meta:
    model = Job
    fields = ('name',)
```